# Sorting in Elasticsearch

Tags: performance, sorting, elasticsearch

Following is the data model of the documents saved in my index:`{"messageId":1,"commentId":1,"likes":1,"stars":1,"time":time in ms,"category":1,"deleted":false,"userid":1}`

Each message has multiple comments (around 2000 in my case)
Indexed documents with routing based on messageId.
I currently have 200 million records of size 31 GB.

- No. of shard: 5
- No. of replicas: 3
  (180 overall store size)
- No. of nodes: 4. Each node has 8GB ram of which I am using 4GB for elasticsearch.

My basic read operation includes fetching `commentIds` for a given `messageId` sorted by likes or stars or time.

Search query:
`curl -XGET localhost:9200/_search?routing=${messageId}&q=messageId:${messageId}&sort=likes:desc&fields=commentId&_source=false`

When i run performance test with 1500 threads the average time taken is 6s and 90% is around 20s! This is the client side values. The took value in response object varies from 10ms to 15s depending on the load.

How can I improve the read performance?

Comment: The cluster has just 1 index

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting the memory limits of your cluster. You should enable Java GC logging (e.g. with `ES_USE_GC_LOGGING`) and see if you're spending a lot of time in GC.

It sounds like your performance test is creating a large number of simultaneous requests. You may be filling your [thread pools](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html). Take a look at:

```
$ curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats/thread_pool?pretty"
```

Finally, it sounds like you have a relatively large number of shards. [A shard is not free](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/kagillion-shards.html) (or [see this benchmark](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/01/07/elasticsearch-how-many-shards/)). If you have `index.number_of_replicas: 3`, you could set `index.number_of_shards: 1` and still get full cluster utilisation.